# AngularJS load different data to same partial based on URL

Tags: angularjs

The problem I'm having here is not being able to find the right question to ask.
I'd like to use a single partial and populate it with different data based on a url. The url would look something like this

```
localhost:8080/#/users/USER_ID
```

Where `users` directs to a user profile partial, and corresponding controller, and `USER_ID` would be sent in to an HTTP request to retrieve user data that would then populate the user profile partial.

Any direction in solving this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check ngRoute: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Thank you @dfsq, this lead me to a very straight forward solution which I posted below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/app.js) which I highly recommend:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('users', {
      url:'/users/:userId',
      templateUrl: 'user.html',
      controller:'UserCtrl'
  })
```

You can then access the `userId` in your controller:

```
App.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'User', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, User) {
'use strict';
/* controller code */

    var req = User.$find($stateParams.userId);

}]);
```

I am also using [angular-rest-mod](https://github.com/platanus/angular-restmod) to make HTTP calls to an api when I do `User.$find(id)`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that was a lot more straight forward than I had anticipated

app.js

```
    $routeProvider.
    when('/user/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'user.html',
        controller: 'userController'
    });
```

Then in the implementation of `userController`, `$routeParams` can be used to retrieve the value of `id` from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I would probably go like this. First I would recommend Ui-Router instead of ngRoute this allows you to create your states for example

```
$stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('A', {
        params: [A,B,C,D,E],
        url: "/A",
        templateUrl: "templates/YourView.html",
        controller: "YourController"
      })

    .state('B', {
        params: [F,G,H,I,J],
        url: "/B",
        templateUrl: "templates/YourView.html",
        controller: "YourController"
      })
```

Basically this says when your Url is "/A" the "YourController" is used and the YourView.html is used so If I understood correct you have 1 view where you want to show different data depending on the Url.By Injecting `'ui.router'`into your module and `$state` into your Controller you can access `$state.current.params`

Example Controller

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state){
//Here you get your params
//This will return you either [A,B,C,D,E] or [F,G,H,I,J] depending if Url is /A or /B

      $scope.showList = $state.current.params;

//Another Possibility with this is to listen for a StateChange

      $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) { 

//Here you can access all Params from the state you just left to the state you are going

});


}]);
```

Now you can just show this in the YourView.html like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in showList">
<p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

So If your at /A the list shows A,B,C,D,E and if you are on /B it shows F,G,H,I,J

I hope this was helpful

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate you taking the time to write this up and I learned something new from your answer. Sorry that my question wasn't worded as clearly as it could have been.

What I was looking to achieve was having N possible URLs stemming from .../users/ where N is the number of registered users and the user ID is used to get user data via HTTP to populate the partial.